# Apple Mach -O (ID) Linker Error, ncurses

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, command-line-tool

I am quite new to C++ programming and I've currently fallen into a very asked problem: Xcode's "Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error".
As I've understood it the problem comes from the standard ncurses library which contains all the getch attributes. The reason why I post this is because I can't really find the solution for it and the error seems to be a little bit difference compared to the other Linker errors.
I am using an OS X computer with Xcode 8, simple command line script as a Xcode project.
This is what it looks like in the issues tab:
[Image view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzyck.png)
Anyway this is my current code if someone actually have time for these things:

Integers

```
int x, y;
int ch;
x = width / 2;
y = height / 2;
```

Map

```
system("clear");

for (int i = 0; i < width+2; i++) //upper row
    cout << "#";
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) //mid rows upways
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) //mid rows sideways
    {
        if (j == 0)
            cout << "#";
        if (i == y && j == x)
            cout << "O";
        else
            cout << " ";
        if (j == width - 1)
            cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (int j = 0; j < height+2; j++)  //bottom row
    cout << "#";
cout << endl;
```

**Problem**

```
if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
{
    switch (getch ())
    {
        case 72:
            x++; //up key
            break;

        case 80:
            //down key
            break;

    }
}
```

I did cut of a lot of other codes but I believe the other stuffs doesn't matter at all. So if you want to know something more about it just tell me and I will edit it.
Thanks!

Comment: How is your Makefile looking ? Or how is the configuration to call the compiler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like you are not linking against libncurses. Either add "-lncurses" to "Other Linker Flags" in build settings (click the project in navigator, select "Build Settings" tab in the editor) or better add libncurses as a linked library (click project file in navigator, select "Build Phases" tab, expand "Link Binary With Libraries", click the plus symbol and type "ncurses", select "libncurses.a" or "libncurses.tbd").

Comment: Wow, this might actually work! But for some reason i got an "Expected statement" error after the first void. Any thoughts?